# Probability of an edge between two vertices

Tags: probability, graph-theory

all!

I have probably extremely simple question, but I need your help.

Say, we have an undirected graph with v= 10 vertices and e=30 edges. What is the probability to have an edge between two vertices?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For the question to make sense, you need to specify what probability model you are talking about.  One reasonable interpretation is that you have $10$ labelled vertices, and you make a random selection of $30$ of the ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ unordered pairs of vertices to be edges of your graph.   Then the probability that a given pair is chosen is $30/45 = 2/3$.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I must be too exhausted) I have posted the answer myself.

Answer (score -1):

That is what happens when you are doing your homework at night.

total possible number of edges: 10!/(2!*8!) = 45
edge_probability = 30 / 45 = **0.67**